# Neo4j Cypher - Return subset of nodes with same type

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Just started learning about graph databases and can't solve this most likely very easy problem (real-world) - any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem**

Given *Node X* find *Subset Y*.

[image: diagram.jpg]

Using a Neo4j Cypher Query - [Direct Image Link](http://cl.ly/image/2C1F3Q0h3L2A)

Comment: Which docs were you using and what do you feel was missing there?

Answer (score 2):

The query below returns your 'X' node, and a collection of the other nodes labeled `A` that are also liked by the same `B` nodes.

```
MATCH (a:A)<-[:likes]-(:B)-[:likes]->(otherA:A)
WHERE a.id = 'X'
RETURN a, COLLECT(otherA)
```

I assume here that you identify your `A` nodes by an `id` property. There is no need to explicitly make sure that `otherA` is never the same as `a`, since Cypher does that for you automatically ([see manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html)).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
MATCH (a {api_id: 182983836})<-[:likes]-(b)-[:likes]->(c) RETURN c
```

Comment: In your solution "c" also can have api_id=182983836